# Hide content DIV and show it after pressing the search button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to do a page search like Google. This page would contain the following:

1. a text box
2. a search button

After I enter a value in the text box and press the button, the result should be put in a `DIV` but this won't be visible before pressing the search button. The content is to be shown only after pressing the search button. How can achieve this by using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `ajax()` function for acheving this.
Check this link:  http://www.codeforest.net/simple-search-with-php-jquery-and-mysql

Comment: jQuery AJAX? Is this some new kind of ajax? :-o

Comment: very thanks for you my friend for help me and provide me this resource.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you hide the div using CSS and when hit to search button it appears as follows.

CSS code

```
#content_div {
   display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".search_button").click(function() {
    $("#content_div").show();
}
```

Comment: in first I very thanks for help me and I try apply your solution but I see after press button search , content is appear but direct hide.why?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you might want to use something like this:

```
 $('#search_results').load('perform_search.php', {query: $('#search_query_input').val()});
```

explanation:

1. #search_results is div where you will put your results
2. load() is jquery's function to update container via ajax
3. perform_search.php is the page which will return you results to be displayed in     #search_results
4. query is the name of the parameter which would be passed to perform_search (like 5. $_REQUEST['query'])
5. #search_query_input is the id of your "text box"

Cheers, hope it will help

Comment: I am very thank for you mr.mkk for help me and cooperation me.